# Realizar soma de valor para inserir em um objeto

Tags: javascript

Tenho o desafio de um curso para resolver, porém estou com dificuldades. [Link do desafio](https://github.com/Rocketseat/bootcamp-launchbase-desafios-01/blob/master/desafios/01-4-aplicacao-operacoes-bancarias.md).

Com o código abaixo, já consegui inserir os objetos com os tipos **credit** e **debit** no **transactions** de **user**. Consegui também listar apenas os objetos com tipo **credit**. Porém, não sei como realizar a soma dos valores de **credit** para depois inserir na propriedade **balance**. Será também que estou seguindo a maneira correta de resolver?

```js
// Crie um programa para realizar operações bancárias na conta de um usuário.

// Comece criando um objeto com o nome do usuário, suas transações e saldo.

const user = {
  name: "Mariana",
  transactions: [],
  balance: 0
};

// O type pode ser credit para créditos e debit para débitos da conta do usuário.
createTransaction({type: 'credit', value: 50.5})
createTransaction({type: 'credit', value: 80})
createTransaction({type: 'debit', value: 40})
createTransaction({type: 'debit', value: 30})

// Crie uma função createTransaction
function createTransaction(transaction) {
  //adicionar uma nova transação no array de transações de um usuário
  user.transactions.push(transaction)
}

// Quanto uma transação for do tipo credit ela deve também somar o valor do crédito no saldo (balance) do usuário.
for (let transaction of user.transactions) {
  const credit = transaction.type === 'credit'
  let sum = 0

  if (credit) {
    sum = sum + transaction.value
    const result = sum + transaction.value.length
    console.log(result)
   
  }
}
```

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta e ser claro ao explicar do que se trata, qual é o prolema e aonde está o problema.

Comment: Qual é a intenção com `const result = sum + transaction.value.length`? Parecia tudo bem até esse ponto. Não basta imprimir `sum` no final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua função `createTransaction` deveria se ocupar também de atualizar o `balance` do usuário com o novo valor apenas inserido ao invés de ter que iterar o array a cada vez para atualizar o valor, você poderia fazer algo como:

```js
const user = {
  name: "Mariana",
  transactions: [],
  balance: 0
};

createTransaction({type: 'credit', value: 50.5})
createTransaction({type: 'credit', value: 80})
createTransaction({type: 'debit', value: 40})
createTransaction({type: 'debit', value: 30});

console.log(user);

function createTransaction(transaction) {
  user.transactions.push(transaction);
  
  if(transaction.type === 'credit')
    user.balance += transaction.value;
}
```

Desta maneira cada vez que você inserir uma nova transação, o valor do saldo será atualizado junto a transação inserida, mas se você deseja apenas inserir as transações e só depois executar o calculo do código você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```js
const user = {
  name: "Mariana",
  transactions: [],
  balance: 0
};

createTransaction({type: 'credit', value: 50.5})
createTransaction({type: 'credit', value: 80})
createTransaction({type: 'debit', value: 40})
createTransaction({type: 'debit', value: 30});

updateBalance();
console.log(user);

function createTransaction(transaction) {
  user.transactions.push(transaction);
}

function updateBalance(){
  for(let transaction of user.transactions){
    if(transaction.type === 'credit')
      user.balance += transaction.value; // += é a mesma coisa que ter user.balance = user.balance + transation.value;
  }
}
```

Com este segundo exemplo você pode inserir quantas transações desejar e só então chamar a função `updateBalance` que calcula o valor do em base as transações existentes no array.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Leo, me ajudou muito. Sou iniciante tanto no Javascript como aqui na comunidade do stackoverflow e talvez não formulei a pergunta corretamente. Mas a dúvida foi muito bem esclarecida por você. Obrigado!!